# Current_user in Controller for Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `Listings Controller` where Users can Create their Listings.

To prevent users to edit other users listings i just had to update every action from

```
Listing to current_user.listings
```

but with Rails 4 the controller got changed and i can't find how to set this up.

My Controller File->

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_listing, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:index]

  # GET /listings
  # GET /listings.json
  def index
    @listings = Listing.all
  end

  # GET /listings/1
  # GET /listings/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /listings/new
  def new
    @listing = Listing.new
  end

  # GET /listings/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /listings
  # POST /listings.json
  def create
    @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.save
        format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @listing }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /listings/1
  # PATCH/PUT /listings/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.update(listing_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /listings/1
  # DELETE /listings/1.json
  def destroy
    @listing.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to listings_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_listing
      @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def listing_params
      params.require(:listing).permit(:title, :description)
    end
end
```

Anyone knows a Solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change from #new to build. So, change all `@listing = Listing.new` to:

```
@listing = current_user.listings.build
```

Then, in set_listing change to:

```
@listing = current_user.listings.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Actually this gives me the Problem, when another user tries to View the Listing -> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ListingsController#show.
Couldn't find Listing with id=13 [WHERE "listings"."user_id" = ?]

Comment: I find the Solution, The Problem was 1.) your point and 2.) the Def action had to be changed so users couldn't edit other users Listings. Thanks anyway.